# Adding crossdomain to root of Azure blob storage

Tags: asp.net, flash, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to access some assets on azure from flash. This requires a crossdomain file to be at the root of the blob, ie http://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/crossdomain.xml

I found that using Azure Storage Explorer there didn't seem to be a way of adding files to the root, I found this post http://www.odity.co.uk/articles/azure-crossdomain-xml-inside-root-of-blob-storage/ which details a programmatic approach. However I have implemented the code and tried to test and am getting the following error which suggests to me it may not be possible to add files to the root?

```
<Error>
<Code>OutOfRangeInput</Code>
<Message>
One of the request inputs is out of range. RequestId:5853bdc0-89ed-47f6-986e-f42badd38e75 Time:2012-06-13T09:37:58.0222882Z
</Message>
</Error>
```

Can anyone clarify if it is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you post the code you're using to create the root container?

Besides that you could also use CloudBerry to create the $root container and upload files to it:

http://blog.cloudberrylab.com/2010/04/cloudberry-explorer-for-azure.html

[image]

Comment: Ah nice and easy with Cloudberry :) The OutOfRangeInput response had me a little worried, a ResourceNotFound response would have been more consistent

Answer (score 2):

an easy way to achieve this is to create a special (blobs) container named "$root" (root starting with a $ sign). In the url of anything placed in this container can be written as under the root, so instead of writing

**http://{my-storage-url}/$root/myFile**

you can use:

**http://{my-storage-url}/myFile**

Last step is copy to the crossdomain.xml file to the $root container. I use Visual Studio to manage files in the azure storage blobs.

- see also

  [Working with the Root Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh488356.aspx)
- Be careful when using crossdomain.xml, since it can render your site vulnerable to attacks.

Comment: I thought this was way more helpful than the accepted answer.  Informative and doesn't need 3rd party software to do something basic.